# match column1,column2 in two files

Tags: awk

I have two files file1.csv & file2.csv

```
file1.csv
Test1;Test3
Test1;Test3
Test1;Test3
Test1;Test3
Test1;Test3
Test1;Test3
Test1;Test3
Test7;Test4
Test7;Test4
Test7;Test4
Test7;Test4
Test7;Test4
Test7;Test4
Test7;Test4



file2.csv
Test1;Test3;12345
Test1;Test3;12345
Test1;Test3;12345
Test1;Test3;12345
Test1;Test3;12345
Test1;Test3;12345
Test1;Test3;12345
Test7;Test4;12346
Test7;Test4;12346
Test7;Test4;12346
Test7;Test4;12346
Test7;Test4;12346
Test7;Test4;12346
Test7;Test4;12346
```

I am trying to loop file1.csv and match with the same in file2.csv and as it would match it should take the output and print it out in a new file
so if column1 and column2 in both files are identical print out a new file but limit it to 3 row of each if match.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2];next}($1,$2 in a){print $0}' identicalValue.csv Originalvalues.csv | head -3
```

Output should be:

```
  Test1;Test3;12345
  Test1;Test3;12345
  Test1;Test3;12345
  Test7;Test4;12346
  Test7;Test4;12346
  Test7;Test4;12346
```

Since file1.csv

```
Test1;Test3
Test1;Test3
Test1;Test3
Test1;Test3
Test1;Test3
Test1;Test3
Test1;Test3
Test7;Test4
Test7;Test4
Test7;Test4
Test7;Test4
Test7;Test4
Test7;Test4
Test7;Test4
```

is equal to file2.csv

```
    Test1;Test3;12345
    Test1;Test3;12345
    Test1;Test3;12345
    Test1;Test3;12345
    Test1;Test3;12345
    Test1;Test3;12345
    Test1;Test3;12345
    Test7;Test4;12346
    Test7;Test4;12346
    Test7;Test4;12346
    Test7;Test4;12346
    Test7;Test4;12346
    Test7;Test4;12346
    Test7;Test4;12346
```

In column 1, column 2 it should just print out 3 values from file2.csv on each match in column1 and column2

Comment: In the example you showed all lines are matched? Can you show an example with unmatched lines? What do you mean by "3 row of each match"? Can you show the output you want to get for the input you provided?

Answer (score 2):

***EDIT:*** Since OP had control M characters in his/her files so adding this solution to deal with it.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=";"} {gsub(/\r/,"")} FNR==NR{a[$1,$2];next} (($1,$2) in a) && ++b[$1,$2]<=3' file1 file2
```

---

---

In case you want to print contents of Input_file2 and match lines from Input_file1 then try following, **this will also keep the match count for each column values to 3 only**.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=";"} FNR==NR{a[$1,$2];next} (($1,$2) in a) && ++b[$1,$2]<=3'  file1  file2
```

Above will print only 3 values per indexes, in case you want to print all values of indexes then try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=";"} FNR==NR{a[$1,$2];next} (($1,$2) in a)'  file1  file2
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Test1;Test3;12345
Test1;Test3;12345
Test1;Test3;12345
Test7;Test4;12346
Test7;Test4;12346
Test7;Test4;12346
```

Comment: Hi, The results is not as expected because awk 'BEGIN{FS=";"} FNR==NR{a[$1,$2];next} (($1,$2) in a) && ++b[$1,$2]<=3'  file1  file2 show the ouput with 3 entries howevewer it only shows 3 entries but my file have many more entries I would like all my values to be displayed if i change <=3 to 4 instead it shows incorrect

Comment: @Leon2020, But you mentioned that you need 3 values ONLY for each first and 2nd Field isn't it?

Comment: 3 values for each match

Comment: @Leon2020, yes that's been taken care in my 1st solution, lemme know if you have queries on same?

Comment: The first solution just print out 3 values, but in my file its more matches but with other values that should match as well so for example Test1;Test3;12345
    Test1;Test3;12345
    Test1;Test3;12345  but not Test1;Test3;12345
Test1;Test3;12345
Test1;Test3;12345
Test7;Test4;12346
Test7;Test4;12346
Test7;Test4;12346

Comment: @Leon2020, Then which 3 values count you are talking about? Please do EDIT your question and let me know then, please do add more clear samples.

Comment: @Leon2020, how about my 2nd solution? Is it working fine for you?

Comment: I have updated my question above, no since I only want to the output to be 3 rows of each match

Comment: @Leon2020, yes I tested it again my 1st solution working absolutely fine for me, I am suspecting that you have Control M chars in your file so can you run `awk 'BEGIN{FS=";"} {gsub(/\r/,"")} FNR==NR{a[$1,$2];next} (($1,$2) in a) && ++b[$1,$2]<=3'  file1  file2` once and lemme know if that works??